# Power converter: Why is audio susceptibility named so?

Tags: power-supply, power-electronics, dc-dc-converter, control-system, transfer-function

In power converter, **audio susceptibility** refers to **line-to-output transfer function**. ( Line= Input voltage ) [ Ref : Fundamentals of Power electronics: Erickson ]

**Why is it named so**- "audio-susceptibility"? Input disturbances can be of any frequency and need not be in audio frequency range, right?

Comment: Conducted Suseceptibility tests will often consist of multiple frequency ranges and test methods. The lower range for power cables could roughly be referred to as "audio". I am somewhat familiar with USA military testing, commercial testing is often similar. For USA military products, MIL-STD-461 CS101 is 30 Hz - 150 kHz. Other paragraphs would test higher frequencies.

Comment: @Mattman944 DO160-G is similar as well. you will have to inject from around 100Hz to 30MHz.

Comment: [Standard Product MIL-STD-461 Conducted Susceptibility Test Criteria](https://mdipower.com/mdi/pdf/app-notes/suscept.pdf).  See CS01 Testing.

Comment: @StainlessSteelRat: Thanks for the doc link. Could you throw some light  why the voltage levels are decreased at higher frequencies? -"At 1.5 kHz to 50 kHz, the signal is linearly decreased."

Comment: @Mattman944 I see the same in DO-160G standard as well. Why are the test voltage levels decreased at higher frequencies?

Answer (score 1):

Power supplies (linear and SMPS) in systems are often shared across multiple subsystems and if either of these systems is an audio amplifier (class-A/class-D), you would have equivalent current ripple in the audio frequency range drawn from the supply. Based on the output impedance of the preceding converter/supply, considerable voltage ripple would also be induced (I've seen ripple upwards of 1V).

This, I feel, might have been the reason for the terminology. Senior members may correct if I am wrong